# How to get data from auto creation rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

i want to get the data from any row or from all rows that are typed and have text

it's like [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyNvL.png)

and i want to grap the data when it multi line [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZJZ.png)

how to get that data from every line (line bye line)

and can i get all line and sore it in a list or database ??

and can i get all line and print them in a file ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

class add_new_radio:
    def __init__(self,  toplevel):
        self.toplevel = toplevel
        self.All_widgets()
        self.toplevel.mainloop()

    def All_widgets(self):
        self.med_name = StringVar()
        self.label_row_general = IntVar()
        self.label_row_general.set(0)
        self.med_ajouter(self.label_row_general.get())

    def ajouter_plus(self):
        self.add_btn.grid_forget()
        self.cancel_btn.grid_forget()
        self.confirme_btn.grid_forget()
        self.print_btn.grid_forget()
        self.nbr = self.label_row_general.get()+1
        self.label_row_general.set(self.nbr)
        self.med_ajouter(self.nbr)

    def med_ajouter(self, row_nbr):
        self.label_row = row_nbr
        Label(self.toplevel, text="Name").grid(
            row=self.label_row, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        Label(self.toplevel, text="Date").grid(
            row=self.label_row, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        Label(self.toplevel, text="From").grid(
            row=self.label_row, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
        Label(self.toplevel, text="Qt/j").grid(row=self.label_row,
                                               column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.medicament_entry = Entry(self.toplevel, text=self.med_name)
        self.date_entry = Entry(self.toplevel)
        self.duree_entry = Entry(self.toplevel)
        self.qt_j_entry = Entry(self.toplevel)

        self.medicament_entry.grid(
            row=self.label_row, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.date_entry.grid(row=self.label_row, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.duree_entry.grid(row=self.label_row, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.qt_j_entry.grid(row=self.label_row, column=7, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.add_btn = Button(self.toplevel, text="Plus",
                              command=self.ajouter_plus)
        self.add_btn.grid(row=self.label_row, column=8,
                          padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=15)

        self.cancel_btn = Button(self.toplevel, text="Annuler")
        self.confirme_btn = Button(
            self.toplevel, text="Ajouter")
        self.print_btn = Button(self.toplevel, text="Imprimer")

        self.cancel_btn.grid(row=self.label_row+1,
                             column=1, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=15)
        self.confirme_btn.grid(row=self.label_row+1,
                               column=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=15)
        self.print_btn.grid(row=self.label_row+1, column=5,
                            padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=15)
if __name__ == '__main__':
     add_new_radio(Tk())
```

and thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the table, you need to keep a reference to the entry widgets. The best way to do this is with a list, which you can make in the `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self,  toplevel):
    self.toplevel = toplevel
    self.entry_list = []
    ...
```

Then in `med_adjouter` you can add them to the list:

```
...
self.qt_j_entry = Entry(self.toplevel)

self.entry_list.append([self.medicament_entry, self.date_entry, self.duree_entry, self.qt_j_entry])

self.medicament_entry.grid(
...
```

Then when you want to get the values from them, you can go through the list and get them like this:

```
def get_data(self):
    data = []
    for row in self.entry_list:
        row_values = []
        for col in row:
            row_values.append(col.get())
        data.append(row_values)
    print(data) #You can then use this list to do other things
```

The `data` list can then be used to put the data into a database or whatever else you want to do with it.

Comment: if i want to delete a data form any row ?

Comment: You can use the `del` command. For example, you could delete the 3rd row of data using `del data[2]` (It's 2 because python indexes start at 0)